# Is it possible to pass json url to controller without saving object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I don't have any models, objects or views. I was task to create a controller that validates a json url. And also to create a post route.

Other than that, I don't know if what I'm doing is correct.

Controller

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  require 'json'
  require 'uri'

  def create
    binding.pry
    JSON.parse(self)
    valid_url?(self)
  end

def valid_url?(url)
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    uri.is_a?(URI::HTTP) && !uri.host.nil?
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    false
end

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  post '/requests', to: 'requests#create', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }

end
```

Comment: this link probably can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306046/938947

Comment: It didn't really help. Thanks though :)